tkinter - configuring widgets using while loop
I have a method that does not work when being called. The program just stops working and nothing happens.
def change_statistics(self):
"""Updates widgets in frame"""
q = 1
new_player_list = player_list[:]      # player_list[:] is a list of player objects.
new_percentage_list = percentage_list[:]  # percentage_list[:] is a list of float numbers where each number represent the percentage attribute of a player object.   

while len(new_percentage_list) != 0:
    for player in new_player_list:
        if player.percentage == max(new_percentage_list):
            player.position = q
            self.children[f"position_{q}"].configure(text = f"{player.position}")
            self.children[f"name_{q}"].configure(text = player.name)
            self.children[f"number_of_w_{q}"].configure(text = f"{player.number_of_w}")
            self.children[f"number_of_games_{q}"].configure(text = f"{player.number_of_games}")
            self.children[f"percentage_{q}"].configure(text = f"{player.percentage}")
            new_player_list.remove(player)
            new_percentage_list.remove(player.percentage)
            q += 1   
            break

I have tried using self.update_idletasks() before break and the only difference it makes is that the method will work for the first loop in the while loop, but then it stops working.

You didn't provide a [mcve], so we have no way to replicate the problem.  Possibly there is a value in percentage_list that doesn't match any of the percentage values in player_list; that value can never be removed from the list, and therefore you have an infinite loop.  Simply sorting player_list, with the percentage as the key, would be a much simpler approach than these multiple loops.
